# Find the residues of $\frac{1}{\sin \pi z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Use Euler's formula $\sin \pi z =\frac{ e^{i\pi z} - e^{-i\pi z}}{2i}$
>   to find the residue of $\frac{1}{\sin \pi z}$. Show that the complex zeros of $\sin \pi z$ are exactly at the integers, and they are each of order $1$. Calculate the residue of $\frac{1}{\sin \pi z}$.

For $\sin \pi z$ , equating it to zero we get using Euler's formula $e^{2i\pi z}=1$ 
So $2i\pi z= 2\pi in$ so $z=n$ for $n$ integer. Hence complex zeros are at exactly integers. How can I show they are of order $1$? Because there are countably many zeros, i.e., integers?
Also I need to find residue.

But then I will get residue for each zero so how should I proceed?

Comment: Use `$\sin$` for $\sin$ instead of $sin$.

Comment: $$\frac1{\sin(\pi(n+w))}=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sin(\pi w)}\sim\frac{(-1)^n}{\pi w}\qquad (w\to0)$$

Comment: $\dfrac{\pi}{\sin\pi x}=\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)$

Comment: Is there any simple way to get this? Sorry I am not an expert to think about gamma function here

Comment: @Kavita "Is there any simple way to get this?" Hmmm... did you **read** my previous comment?

Comment: @MyGlasses True, but how does this help?

Comment: Yes I read it. But what is $w$ there?

Comment: @Kavita If $z\to n$, $z=n+w$ with $w\to0$. (Aside: somebody posts a comment, you miss something in it (as it happens, some trivial point, but anyway), and... and you stay silent? This does not seem optimal, does it?)

Comment: The gamma function has no zeroes @MyGlasses.

Comment: @MyGlasses And anyway, how does this formula help in solving the question asked?

Comment: @Did May I know how your hint is useful ? Sorry but I am afraid to say that I am not getting how this is useful

Comment: Sorry, I must wrote $\infty$ points.

Comment: @Kavita Sure you may: your notes must explain somewhere that, if $$f(z)\sim\frac{c}{z-z_0}$$ when $z\to z_0$, then the residue of $f$ at $z_0$ is $____$. Apply, rinse, rejoice.

Comment: $\sin \pi z =\dfrac{ e^{i\pi z} - e^{-i\pi z}}{2i}=0$ imply $e^{2i\pi z}=1$ then $2i\pi z=2k\pi i$ or $z=k$.

Comment: The residue is C but there are many zeros so what about other zeros? Please instead of giving some hint steps it will be my pleasure if you clearly give me the answer

Comment: @Kavita And this is the exact point where we might disagree since in the present case, hints are **much preferable** to a full answer... Anyway, if you know how to compute the residue at each pole $n$, why do you even care that there are infinitely many poles?

Comment: @MyGlasses Yeah, *as the OP says in their question*. What is the point of your comment?

Comment: @Kavita No, the residue is a **number**, not a function. Say, which textbook/notes are you following?

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sin \pi z =\dfrac{ e^{i\pi z} - e^{-i\pi z}}{2i}=0$ imply $e^{2i\pi z}=1$ then $2i\pi z=2k\pi i$ or $z=k$.

also the residues in $z=k$ are
$$\lim_{z\to k}(z-k)\dfrac{1}{\sin \pi z}=\dfrac{(-1)^k}{\pi}$$
with l'hopital rule.

Comment: Using L'Hopital to compute a limit of $(z-z_0)/(f(z)-f(z_0))$ is plainly absurd since the limit of the ratio is $1/f'(z_0)$ *by definition of the derivative of a function* and L'Hopital builds upon the derivative.

Answer (score 2):

The function has simple poles at the integers. If $f$ has a simple pole at $z_0$, its Laurent expansion is
$$
f(z)=\frac{c_{-1}}{z-z_0}+c_0+c_1(z-z_0)+\dotsb
$$
so it's clear that
$$
c_{-1}=\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)
$$
Conversely, if this limit exists (finite) and is not zero, then $f$ has a simple pole at $z_0$.

If $n$ is an integer, we have
$$
\lim_{z\to n}\frac{z-n}{\sin(\pi z)}=
\lim_{w\to0}\frac{w}{\sin(\pi w+n\pi)}
$$
using $z-n=w$. Distinguish between $n$ odd and even, remembering a basic trig formula.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Use the formula: If $f(z_0)\neq 0$ and $g$ has a simple pole at $z_0$ then 
$$Res(\frac{f}{g},z_0)= =\frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$$